# Typehint function which takes mixed type dictionary and returns mixed type dict with mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm wondering how to type hint the following:

```py
def f(d, n):
    return {(n, key): d[key] for key in d}

dd = {
    1.0: 10.2,
    2.0: 11.8,
    "T1": 300,
    "T2": 300,
}
nn = "Name"


f(d = dd, n = nn)
# returns:
# {('Name', 1.0): 10.2,
# ('Name', 2.0): 11.8,
# ('Name', 'T1'): 300,
# ('Name', 'T2'): 300}
```

I have tried the following:

```py
def f(
    d : Mapping[Union[str, float], float], 
    n : str) -> Dict[Tuple[str, float], float]:
    return {(n, key): d[key] for key in d}

dd = {
    1.0: 10.2,
    2.0: 11.8,
    "T1": 300,
    "T2": 300,
}
nn = "Name"


f(d = dd, n = nn)
```

which gives the error:

```
main.py:6: error: Key expression in dictionary comprehension has incompatible type "Tuple[str, Union[str, float]]"; expected type "Tuple[str, float]"
main.py:17: error: Argument "d" to "f" has incompatible type "Dict[object, float]"; expected "Mapping[Union[str, float], float]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this though.

Comment: The first error is correct, the return type of your dictionry *is* `Dict[Tuple[str, Union[str, float]], float]` so you can fix that. Also, just type annotate `dd`, so `dd: Dict[Union[str, float], float] = {....` but as stated below, the approach with generics is probably cleaner unless you really want to prevent any other types than the above

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest approaching the problem differently. Rather than trying to specify the specific types, because your function doesn't really rely on the keys being strings or floats, make it generic like this:

```
T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")
T3 = TypeVar("T3")

def f(d: Mapping[T1, T2], n: T3) -> Dict[Tuple[T3, T1], T2]:
    return {(n, key): d[key] for key in d}
```

This passes the `mypy` check:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

It becomes much easier to understand now, because you're no longer deducing what should be `Union`s and what shouldn't. If `mypy` sees that `T1` needs to be a `Union` for a particular case, it will infer that itself.

But to answer your actual question:

```
main.py:6: error: Key expression in dictionary comprehension has incompatible type "Tuple[str, Union[str, float]]"; expected type "Tuple[str, float]"
```

This error happens in your code because your tuple's second element (the key) is a `float`, whereas the input keys are a `Union[str, float]`. You are trying to force a potential `str` into a `float`.

```
main.py:17: error: Argument "d" to "f" has incompatible type "Dict[object, float]"; expected "Mapping[Union[str, float], float]"
```

This is an extension of the above error, showing how the whole return type changes when the type of the tuple's second element changes. Fixing your issue would get rid of both of these.